# what to do if the error "Listener failed" Kafka Spring Boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka

producer project-financemicroservice:

```
@Configuration
public class KafkaConfig {

    @Bean
    public NewTopic topic() {
        return TopicBuilder
                .name("SendBuffer")
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public ProducerFactory<Long, SendKafkaDTO> producerFactory() {
        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(producerConfigs());
    }

    @Bean
    public Map<String, Object> producerConfigs() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
        props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, LongSerializer.class);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonSerializer.class);
        // See https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#producerconfigs for more properties
        return props;
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaTemplate<Long, SendKafkaDTO> kafkaTemplate() {
        return new KafkaTemplate<Long, SendKafkaDTO>(producerFactory());
    }
}
```

```
@Service
public class KafkaService {

    protected final KafkaTemplate<Long, SendKafkaDTO> template;

    public KafkaService(KafkaTemplate<Long, SendKafkaDTO> template) {
        this.template = template;
    }

    public void sendBufferKafka(EmployeeDTO employee, LocalDate data, BigDecimal totalAmount){

        SendKafkaDTO send = new SendKafkaDTO(
                employee.getEmail(),
                employee.getFirstName(),
                data,
                totalAmount
        );

        template.send("SendBuffer", 1L, send);
    }
}
```

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
public class SendKafkaDTO {
    private String email;
    private String firstName;
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    private LocalDate data;
    private BigDecimal totalAmount;
}
```

Consumer project-messagemicrosevice:

```
@Configuration
@EnableKafka
public class KafkaConfig {

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<Long, SendKafkaDTO> ConsumerFactory() {
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(ConsumerConfigs());
    }

    @Bean
    public Map<String, Object> ConsumerConfigs() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
        props.put(JsonDeserializer.TRUSTED_PACKAGES, "*");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG,"sendKafka");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, ErrorHandlingDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, ErrorHandlingDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ErrorHandlingDeserializer.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS, LongDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ErrorHandlingDeserializer.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS, JsonDeserializer.class);
        return props;
    }

    @Bean
    KafkaListenerContainerFactory<ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<Long, SendKafkaDTO>>
    kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Long, SendKafkaDTO> factory =
                new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(ConsumerFactory());
        factory.setConcurrency(3);
        factory.getContainerProperties().setPollTimeout(3000);
        return factory;
    }
}
```

```
    @KafkaListener(id = "sendKafka", topics = "SendBuffer")
    private void kafkaListen(@Payload SendKafkaDTO sendKafkaDTO) {
        System.out.println(sendKafkaDTO);
    }
```

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
public class SendKafkaDTO {
    private String email;
    private String firstName;
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    private LocalDate data;
    private BigDecimal totalAmount;
}
```

After I send a kafka message and the listener receives it, an error appears in the console

```
org.springframework.kafka.listener.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener failed
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.decorateException(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2946) ~[spring-kafka-3.0.11.jar:3.0.11]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.checkDeser(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2994) ~[spring-kafka-3.0.11.jar:3.0.11]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeOnMessage(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2849) ~[spring-kafka-3.0.11.jar:3.0.11]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.lambda$doInvokeRecordListener$57(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2772) ~[spring-kafka-3.0.11.jar:3.0.11]
    at io.micrometer.observation.Observation.lambda$observe$4(Observation.java:544) ~[micrometer-observation-1.11.4.jar:1.11.4]
    at io.micrometer.observation.Observation.observeWithContext(Observation.java:603) ~[micrometer-observation-1.11.4.jar:1.11.4]
    at io.micrometer.observation.Observation.observe(Observation.java:544) ~[micrometer-observation-1.11.4.jar:1.11.4]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2770) ~[spring-kafka-3.0.11.jar:3.0.11]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeWithRecords(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2622) ~[spring-kafka-3.0.11.jar:3.0.11]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2508) ~[spring-kafka-3.0.11.jar:3.0.11]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2150) ~[spring-kafka-3.0.11.jar:3.0.11]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeIfHaveRecords(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1505) ~[spring-kafka-3.0.11.jar:3.0.11]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.pollAndInvoke(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1469) ~[spring-kafka-3.0.11.jar:3.0.11]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1344) ~[spring-kafka-3.0.11.jar:3.0.11]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.run(CompletableFuture.java:1804) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1623) ~[na:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.DeserializationException: failed to deserialize
    at org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.SerializationUtils.deserializationException(SerializationUtils.java:158) ~[spring-kafka-3.0.11.jar:3.0.11]
    at org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.ErrorHandlingDeserializer.deserialize(ErrorHandlingDeserializer.java:182) ~[spring-kafka-3.0.11.jar:3.0.11]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.parseRecord(Fetcher.java:1429) ~[kafka-clients-3.4.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.access$3400(Fetcher.java:133) ~[kafka-clients-3.4.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher$CompletedFetch.fetchRecords(Fetcher.java:1661) ~[kafka-clients-3.4.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher$CompletedFetch.access$1900(Fetcher.java:1497) ~[kafka-clients-3.4.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.fetchRecords(Fetcher.java:717) ~[kafka-clients-3.4.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.collectFetch(Fetcher.java:683) ~[kafka-clients-3.4.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.pollForFetches(KafkaConsumer.java:1314) ~[kafka-clients-3.4.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1243) ~[kafka-clients-3.4.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1216) ~[kafka-clients-3.4.1.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.pollConsumer(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1676) ~[spring-kafka-3.0.11.jar:3.0.11]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doPoll(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1651) ~[spring-kafka-3.0.11.jar:3.0.11]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.pollAndInvoke(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1452) ~[spring-kafka-3.0.11.jar:3.0.11]
    ... 3 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException: failed to resolve class name. Class not found [com.financemicroservice.DTOModels.SendKafkaDTO]
    at org.springframework.kafka.support.mapping.DefaultJackson2JavaTypeMapper.getClassIdType(DefaultJackson2JavaTypeMapper.java:142) ~[spring-kafka-3.0.11.jar:3.0.11]
    at org.springframework.kafka.support.mapping.DefaultJackson2JavaTypeMapper.toJavaType(DefaultJackson2JavaTypeMapper.java:103) ~[spring-kafka-3.0.11.jar:3.0.11]
    at org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer.deserialize(JsonDeserializer.java:572) ~[spring-kafka-3.0.11.jar:3.0.11]
    at org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.ErrorHandlingDeserializer.deserialize(ErrorHandlingDeserializer.java:179) ~[spring-kafka-3.0.11.jar:3.0.11]
    ... 15 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.financemicroservice.DTOModels.SendKafkaDTO
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:496) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:475) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:291) ~[spring-core-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.kafka.support.mapping.DefaultJackson2JavaTypeMapper.getClassIdType(DefaultJackson2JavaTypeMapper.java:138) ~[spring-kafka-3.0.11.jar:3.0.11]
    ... 18 common frames omitted
```

As I understood from the error, the listener needs a com class to convert from JSON to a java object.financemicroservice.DTOModels.SendKafkaDTO, but how can I get it if it is in another project that is a producer?

I tried to configure configs in different ways, added that I trust deserialization of props.put(JsonDeserializer.TRUSTED_PACKAGES, "*") to all files.